Flip touchscreen horizontally
How can horizontally flip a touchscreen in Raspberry Pi OS? I already flipped the visible part of the screen using xrandr --output HDMI-1 --reflect x after having changed from Wayland to X11. And it works perfectly fine, but now the touchscreen pointer does not work correctly anymore according to what is shown on the screen. In other words, I only flipped the screen but not the touchscreen. If I click with my finger on the right side of the screen the click is done on the other left side. This only concerns the touchscreen part. Using a mouse it works perfectly fine, but not with the touchscreen.
How can I achieve the right clicking position with the touchscreen?

Try: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/55882/5538
